# Firefox incorrectly displays items when loading a mvc razor page, select2 js

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, html, user-interface, jquery-select2

Firefox 59.0  Project MVC.NET. Use https://select2.github.io js lib for select elements
On the View there are many elements such as:

```
                    <div class="control control_medium control_select">
                    <select name="@nameof(Model.Query.BudgetCycleIds)"
                            @Html.AjaxViewSubmitOnChange()
                            @Html.AsugfAutoComplete()
                            multiple="multiple">
                        <option value="0">Все</option>
                        @foreach (var budgetCycle in Model.BudgetCycles)
                        {
                            <option value="@budgetCycle.Id" @(Model.Query.BudgetCycleIds?.Contains(budgetCycle.Id) ?? false ? "selected" : "")>@budgetCycle.Name</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                </div>
```

Same in the html:

```
<select name="BudgetCycleIds" ajaxview-submit-onchange="" asugf-select2="" multiple="" tabindex="-1" class="select2-hidden-accessible" aria-hidden="true">
                        <option value="0">Все</option>
                            <option value="13" selected="">2010 - 2012</option>
                            <option value="14">2011 - 2013</option>
                            <option value="9">2012 - 2014</option>
                            <option value="5">2013 - 2015</option>
                            <option value="6">2014 - 2016</option>
                            <option value="7">2015 - 2017</option>
                            <option value="1">2016 - 2018</option>
                            <option value="2">2017 - 2019</option>
                            <option value="4">2018 - 2020</option>
                    </select>
```

Normal UI (before loading):
[image]

Not normal UI (in a second after loading):
[image]

Normal UI (in two second after loading):

[image]

The other browsers are the same, but very fast, and the user does not see the interface jumps.
How to make sure that the wrong interface does not appear

Comment: It looks like you have some kind of client-side library that takes ownership of the dropdown and then changes it. The code you posted shows nothing like that, so an answer based on what you posted is impossible.

Comment: this only occurs in the Firefox

Comment: As Peter said, we would need to see the JS code that attaches to the `<select>`. But one solution would be to hide the element initially (`<select style="display: none;">`)  and only show it after the JS code has initialized the control.

Comment: Use https://select2.github.io js lib for select elements

Answer (score 0):

Not a good solution (because the layout is "jumps")
add hidden class

```
 <option class="hidden" value="0">Все</option>
                    @foreach (var budgetCycle in Model.BudgetCycles)
                    {
                        <option class="hidden" value="@budgetCycle.Id" @(Model.Query.BudgetCycleIds?.Contains(budgetCycle.Id) ?? false ? "selected" : "")>@budgetCycle.Name</option>
                    }
```